# jquery with iframe close button issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

I have one html file. in that file i have a link with id "send-this-page-link", once the user click this, it will display a div with id "send-this-page", that div has a iframe, which is loading a php file. in the php file has a close button, and cancel link, while the user lick the close button in the iframe, that whole div has to close ("send-this-page-link"), as well it has to do the same, when the user click on cancel link.

i used jquery and made the link button to close it's parent. but it not work. i used the live function, till no chance, any one help me?

or any other good way?

thanks for advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this. it work good.

> ('#parentPrice', window.parent.document)

Answer (score 1):

seems a bit of a strange line of code - a bit overkill, but if you give your iframe an id, you should be able to use a link like this:

`<a href="window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe-id').parentNode.removeChild(window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe-id'))">Close</a>`

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure the **parent-page** and the **iframe** have the same domain so the iframe can do something to the parent-page, you can confirm this by write the following code in both page:

```
alert(document.domain);
```

Comment: do you use firebug, are there any error message in the console?

Comment: no errors. my issue is need to hide the div is in the current html file, and the close button is loaded iframe php file. how to close using loaded button from this current html div?